# How to use ssh session with no color formatting

Tags: ssh, colors, escape-characters

How to create ssh session by `ssh foo@bar` except not any color format?  The only require is the setting should be declared at the `ssh` command and can't be setting at config file.

As an aside, the reason is I want get the ssh shell result to a Scala program, [git repos more detail if you interested](https://github.com/LoranceChen/scall).  So, the color codes, such as`[03m`(maybe others), should be removed.  I can't expect remote host make some setting and let it no color.

### UPDATE

1. about `JSch` SSH library, there is some setting to explain:

   1. `setPtyType("dumb")`, the parameter `dumb` setting the session with `dumb` emulation terminal similar with `Linux`, `VT100` etc. The `dumb` emulation terminal is not any colors codes in result. Use `echo $TERM` will print `dumb` after setting this property.
   2. `setPty(bool enable)` default is `false` but if I explicit setting `setPty(false)` the result will be break. Unfortunately I haven't find a API to get the pty values at runtime and the library is lack of document even though it is Java de-facto standard SSH library.
2. why I want use ssh in a ssh?

   1. This feature is need because some key file maybe on remote host.So, I need login the remote host first and then login another host.
   2. login a terminal and use ssh connect to another host is a normal operation.
3. What's the Scala library output if it has some color codes?
   steps:

   - use `JSch` create a ssh session connection.
   - use `ls`
   - connect to new shell
   - use `cd /var` on the new shell
   - use `ls` on the new shell.

```
//use `JSch` create a ssh session connection. 
val shell = new Shell(Auth("hostname", "username", 22, "pwd"))
//use `ls` 
shell.exc("ls")

//connect to new shell   
val newShell = shell.newShell(Auth("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "root", 22, "pwd")).right.get

//use `cd /var` on the new shell  
newShell.exc("cd /var")
//use `ls` on the new shell.
newShell.exc("ls")

newShell.exit()

shell.disconnect()
```

The command `shell.exc("ls")` output perfectly because I'm use `dumb` property to `JSch.setPtyType()`.  It not color codes print.

The problem of the color codes occurred at `newShell.exc("ls")`, it prints:

```
[0m[01;34mbackups[0m  [01;34mcache[0m  [01;34mlib[0m  [01;34mlocal[0m  [01;36mlock[0m  [01;34mlog[0m  [01;34mmail[0m  [01;34mopt[0m  [01;36mrun[0m  [01;34mspool[0m  [30;42mtmp[0m
```

Obviously, it contains some color codes.  `val newShell` is generated by a bare command `ssh -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no foo@bar`, so it different with `JSch` ways.

Currently, I just want dispose the color codes and keep the response information only contains text:

```
backups  cache  lib  local  lock  log  mail  opt  run  spool  tmp
```

Hope it will be clear the question. Thanks again.

### UPDATE again

Sorry for my two mistake.

1. `TERM=dumb` is needn't at all because `JSch` has setting `dumb` and new ssh will fooling it.
2. `setPty(true)`(or -T parameter) is affect, my test was fail because of another problem that the `MAGIC_SPLIT` constants should be start/end with `\n` rather then `\r\n` in this mode.

#### What's the changes should I do?

Use `setPty(true)` for all message protocol, which contains `JSch` and `ssh` with -T parameter, rather then `dumb` because it is more clear response.

#### What's the problem left?

Some remote host will response a error message `stdin: is not a tty` after success login the remote host that is matter because of `echo $?` will be fail. But it is off topic already.

#### About this topic

Back to the question `how to use ssh session with no color formatting?`, the answer is use `-T` parameter for `ssh`.

And finally, thanks a lot for @sourcejedi's patience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just do it.

Local programs whose output is piped to another program, are expected to detect that they are not connected to any terminal, so they can't use any color codes (which vary between terminals, hence the TERM environment variable).

And when the local program `ssh` is piped to another program, and you do not pass the options `-tt`, it suppresses allocation of a "pseudo-terminal" and uses pipes instead.  See also `man ssh`.

If your code was allocating a "pseudo-terminal" instead of using a pipe to capture the output, you <del>would</del> should notice that fact.  In most contexts the code required is more obscure and longer than if you used a pipe; most times you don't need (or, as you say, want) the extra features of a PTY.

---

### EXCEPT I think your question is wrong (in the UPDATE part)

Suppose you're actually not running `ssh`, and instead running `sshpass -p '${auth.password}' ssh`...

sshpass, as per it's `man` page, is running ssh "in a dedicated TTY, fooling it into thinking it is getting the password from an interactive user" (yep, it's another PTY).

In that case, you would need to disable the normal terminal behaviour again for the inner SSH connection.  I.e. using `ssh -T` (not `ssh -t` as in one of the code commits!).

I think prefixing with `TERM=dumb` does also achieve a very similar effect.  It's a bit of a work-around.  `ssh -T` avoids the need to mess around with TERM.  But I tested `TERM=dumb sshpass sh -c 'echo $TERM'` on my computer, it seems to pass through OK, and maybe it feels simpler to you.

Next question:  Why is your testing telling you this is necessary, when your code is *also* already working to set `TERM=dumb`, before you launch the (inner) `ssh` command?  You'd expect the  `ssh` to have inherited `TERM=dumb` already.  Look at the code for Jsch.  I think your `setPtyType("dumb")` won't have any effect, for the reason that you don't have any call to `setPty(true)`.

My understanding is contradicted by your assertion that `setPty(false)` "breaks", but you don't say how.

Comment: Do you means I should use a pipe, so `ssh foo@bar` is enough? But it has color codes.

Comment: hi, with `-T` parameter, the output is pure text, maybe it close to my need.But why the session can't find `ll` command?

Comment: 1) you're being unhelpfully vague, you need to provide an example of a command that uses color codes that you don't want to.  For all you were telling us, it could be a specific command that is already reported as behaving badly.

Comment: 2) Why are you linking to code that uses an SSH library, connects to the remote host, and then runs a second ssh client on the remote host, which connects to the same remote host? It's clearly using the `Auth` details twice.  Why are you referring to code that does this, it can only cause us confusion as to which instance of the ssh client you need to change settings on.  3) the `ll` thing is a separate question, please ask a new one providing all relevant details

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry not put enough detail information at first.The deep implement method of the library is append at **UPDATE**, hope it will be clearer.

Comment: Probably `ll` is an alias. Noninteractive shells do not load aliases. You should probably not use aliases at all, anyway. The straightforward workaround in the meantime is to spell out the full command (`ls -l`?)

Comment: @LoranceChen ok, apologies for my violent confusion, but I believe the wider context _is_ relevant, that your question is wrong, and you could have avoided this confusion by actually testing the out-of-context command.  See edit.

Comment: @LoranceChen updated with answer to my puzzle.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are some my mistake to puzzled you and I'm have a new idea to continue my work.